# what si the meaning of a first chance exception

Tags: c#, xml

When I debug my code I've written in c# I get this error from a third party component:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.Xml.XPath.XPathException'
>        occurred in System.Xml.dll

What does this mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may take a look at the [following blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidklinems/archive/2005/07/12/438061.aspx) which provides an overview of what first chance exceptions represent.

Answer (score 2):

First-chance exceptions are special exceptions that are raised so that the debugger can break immediately. This is useful so that you can see exceptions immediately at the point they occur, and not at the point where they are caught.

If a first-chance exception is not followed by a "normal" exception that causes the debugger to break, it means that an exception was thrown and later caught (i.e., someone handled it).

Original source: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/105675

Comment: There's nothing special about them. All exceptions are first-chance exceptions at first.

Comment: @John: "special" as in "quite a lot of junior developers don't even know they exist".

Comment: by that token, quite a lot of .NET is special.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want that message, likely you can get rid of it by opening the "Exceptions" dialogue box (ctrl-alt-e) and de-selecting the "thrown" option for "Common Language Runtime Exceptions."  Be prepared that the "thrown" option might be selected only for a subset of that tree entry.